# Size of HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

How to get the number of time windows in the below example? Currently it says that there are 2 time windows, though there are 3 time windows, each defined by open and close times.

```
    Map<String, String> _timeWindows = new HashMap<String, String>();
    _timeWindows.put("open", "123");
    _timeWindows.put("close", "124");
    _timeWindows.put("open", "523");
    _timeWindows.put("close", "524");
    _timeWindows.put("open", "823");
    _timeWindows.put("close", "824");

    System.out.println(_timeWindows.size());
```

Comment: because the map key is like a Set. It wont allow duplicate values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys are unique in all maps.

if you want to add more than one value using same key. Use [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html)

```
 MultiMap timeWindows = new MultiValueMap();
        timeWindows.put("open", "123");
        timeWindows.put("close", "124");
        timeWindows.put("open", "523");
        timeWindows.put("close", "524");
        timeWindows.put("open", "823");
        timeWindows.put("close", "824");

        System.out.println("timeWindows : "+timeWindows);
```

output : `timeWindows : {open=[123, 523, 823], close=[124, 524, 824]}`

Comment: How to import MultiMap into the class?

Comment: Its a third party jar. Download it http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonscollectionsjar.htm

Answer (score 1):

A HashMap contains unique keys. So when a new key is inserted, which already exists, it overwrites it's corresponding value. So, your map currently has just 2 key-value pairs.

Given your question, I guess you need a `Window` class, with type as `enum`, and the value as String:

```
class Window {
    private String value;
    private WindowType type;

    enum WindowType {
        OPEN, CLOSED;
    }

    // constructor, getters.
}
```

and then maintain a `Set<Window>` or `List<Window>` depending upon your requirement.

If your value denotes time, then you should really store it as time, and not String. I would suggest to use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Keys are unique in HashMap. It will have only these values:

```
_timeWindows.put("open", "823");
_timeWindows.put("close", "824");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since keys are unique in `Map` when you put "open" and "close" more than one time, it merely ovverides the old values and it keeps the same `key`. So, correctly it has only two elements with `keys`: "open", "close".